# OpenCV - which feature should I use to detect areas in image

Tags: opencv, feature-detection

I am a newbie to OpenCV and am running into some issues.

I am working on a system that will detect particles in a tube full of fluid. To detect the particles we have a robot that spins the tube for a few seconds and then stops the tube.  We then take a series of images of the just stopped tube.  If there are particles they should continue to move after the tube is stopped and therefore show up in different positions in the images.

The problem I have is the amount of the fluid in the tube varies.  Therefore, the Region of Interest (ROI) where we are concerned about the movement varies.  The image below shows the meniscus at the top of the ROI and the tube bottom in the red rectangles and the ROI in the green rectangle.

My question is which approach should I use in OpenCV to detect the meniscus which will move up and down as the amount of fluid varies?

I have played with feature detection using a Cascade Classifier, but that has been problematic because the training is not resulting in a classifier that works, but I am still working on it.  Since the meniscus has a regular shape (the downward facing crescent) should I try a different approach with some sort of geometric shape detector? If so, how does one define this downward facing crescent shape to OpenCV.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Seeing as you have a pretty constant image quality, resolution, lighting conditions etc. you could pre-process your image with a fixed set of parameters before attempting feature detection. For example greatly increase contrast and then perform your own binary threshold - [here's a very crude example of that](http://i.imgur.com/qX50Bq1.png). With an image like this a basic contour function could work out for you. I do see that the bottom part isn't quite right but since the ROI is constant you can apply diff. thresholds on diff. ROIs.

Comment: Also, about cascade classifier, from what I remember (don't hold me on this) parts of it are patented and not allowed for commercial use. It's possible that by now opencv has supported more algorithms for it but do keep in mind the patent issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Just to make sure I understand this.  I would increase the contrast greatly (thanks for the image), find the lowest threshold from light to dark, and then do any adjustment to get the "proper" top of the ROI.  Is that correct?  If so, what OpenCV function would you recommend to find this threshold.

Comment: Doo.  Just reread your comment.  I will give findContour() a try,

Comment: I'll provide more details if needed when I get back from work but you probably get the gist. findContour should do the job here quite nicely.